# huponexit for non-login shells

Tags: bash

This is a followup to [Do background processes get a SIGHUP when logging off?](https://serverfault.com/questions/117152/do-background-processes-get-a-sighup-when-logging-off).

It seems that `huponexit` only works for login shells. How do I get that behavior for non-login shells, e.g. the ones that are started in my terminal window?

Sending `HUP` to the bash from where the processes have been started works as expected, but `huponexit` doesn't.

Comment: How about `nohup`, `screen`, `tmux`, ...?

Comment: I want the opposite behavior of nohup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your own code to run when the shell exits.

```
trap 'kill -HUP $(jobs -lp) 2>/dev/null || true' EXIT
```

(My earlier proposal of `trap 'kill -HUP $$' EXIT` doesn't work as of bash 4.2, because if I understand the source correctly bash skips part of its normal cleanup, including HUP resending, when it's already processing an exit condition.)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - the kill doesn't seem to be sent to the child processes in the first place, since the shell isn't a login shell...

Comment: @lxgr Ah, right. This doesn't work from a trap. Ok, then you can do it by sending the HUP signal explicitly. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
trap 'kill -HUP -$$' exit
```

I can't seem to add a comment above. Prefix a negative sign to denote a process group. I think this will hang up **all** child processes spawned by the shell, include grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and so forth.