# nohup daemon process dies when terminal is close

Tags: linux, rsync, terminal, daemon, nohup

I'm trying to copy the contents of a remote server to my local computer. Here is the command that I'm using:

```
nohup rsync -chavP -e 'ssh -p 23' --stats user@ipaddress:~/great/stuff /volume1/code > ~/rsynclog &
```

My understanding of the above command is that it should be creating a daemon process (`nohup &`) which is wholly disconnected from my terminal session. As such, I should be able to safely close my terminal and have the process continue on its merry way.

The process does start as expected. However, if I close my terminal session, the process no longer shows up in `ps aux | grep rsync`. The process has obviously died as you can see in the rsynclog:

```
receiving incremental file list
Killed by signal 1.
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(615) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

This is happening as a direct result of my closing the terminal. If I leave the terminal open for hours then rsync works fine. As soon as I close it, however, the process dies.

Does anyone know enough about `nohup` to explain why it doesn't seem to be working here? I'm creating the terminal using `PuTTY` in `Windows`, but I also tried it through a terminal on my ubuntu machine and got the same result.

I tried a simpler test with `nohup sleep 100000 &` and this DID work! However, it is unclear to me why that daemon keeps living while rsync dies...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do background processes get a SIGHUP when logging off?](https://serverfault.com/questions/117152/do-background-processes-get-a-sighup-when-logging-off)

Answer (score 1):

Use `screen` or `tmux`. This is not the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend `screen` for long running jobs but you can also use a BASH built-in command `disown` to remove jobs from current shell.

```
# help disown
disown: disown [-h] [-ar] [jobspec ...]
    Remove jobs from current shell.

    Removes each JOBSPEC argument from the table of active jobs.  Without
    any JOBSPECs, the shell uses its notion of the current job.

Options:
  -a    remove all jobs if JOBSPEC is not supplied
  -h    mark each JOBSPEC so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the
    shell receives a SIGHUP
  -r    remove only running jobs

Exit Status:
Returns success unless an invalid option or JOBSPEC is given.
```

Answer (score 0):

`nohup` will not detach process from it's input terminal but the `sleep` command does not read anything from stdin so it will continue to run while `rsync` does read stdin so when you close the terminal it will detach from that terminal and `rsync` will receive EOF or EIO.

Try to execute `nohup cat &` to see a similar error in nohup.out.

Try to use `<dev/null`. If it does not work then you will need to use `screen`.

Also check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process