# Will the background process exit when you log out in linux?

Tags: bash, background-process

```
[root@~]# ./file.sh &
```

I don't know if `$!` will terminate if I just log out immediately?

Comment: Depends on if huponexit is set, see http://serverfault.com/questions/117152/do-background-processes-get-a-sighup-when-logging-off

Answer (score 2):

`disown` the job and it won't. If it's the only thing running in the background, you'd do `disown %1`. Otherwise it would be the job number given in square brackets when you start the job.

Comment: Who is right,you or @Kyle Brandt?

Comment: They're both right.  There's more to it than you understand.  See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/115999/if-i-launch-a-background-process-and-then-log-out-will-it-continue-to-run 

disown forks the process from the shell, so it won't be sent a `SIGHUP` on exit even if `huponexit` is `on`.

Comment: I am right times infinity squared + 2.  You want disown the job if you can.  Ideally I would recommend that you run the job with screen or maybe nohup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the exact answer to this question.

I do know that to detach from the console requires more than just redirecting to /dev/null. You need to consider using `setsid` as well as redirecting `1>/dev/null` and `2>/dev/null`.