# SLURM, SSH, adn NOHUP Behaviour

Tags: centos, ssh, bash, centos7, slurm

I am the administrator of a cluster running on CentOS and using SLURM to send jobs from a login node to compute nodes. Recently, a user complained about some unexpected behaviour with their jobs. If a user starts a job with `srun` and then logs out, the job keeps running as expected. However, when the user is disconnected by a SSH timeout, the job is killed. I've replicated this behaviour by killing a shell running a job using `kill -1 ShellJobID` and the job is killed. Examining the SLURM logs indicates that the job actually received a `SIGKILL` and not a `SIGHUP` based on the line `WSIGTERM 9`. Additionally, if I run `kill -1 ActiveSrunJob`, the jobs exits with `WSIGTERM 9`. What about logging out using `exit` prevents the SLURM job from being cancelled? I was under the impression, and research seems to back that, `SIGHUP` is propagated to a shell's children on logout. Am I missing something or completely off base?

Comment: See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/117152/do-background-processes-get-a-sighup-when-logging-off) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/115999/if-i-launch-a-background-process-and-then-log-out-will-it-continue-to-run).

Comment: I had come across the first link before, but not the second. Thanks for your quick reply. Using both your links, the BASH manual, and [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318369/what-happens-to-background-jobs-after-exiting-the-shell), I was able to fully understand that this is the expected behaviour. I think the explanation given in the link I put above helped me out the most. Thanks for the help and pointing me in the right direction, Massimo!