# No hangup signal by default

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen

I have a server running ubuntu server. It is behind a proxy...I don't know if that makes a difference. But I have found that a couple of processes I've tried, get terminated when I log out of the SSH session. For instance, I have ipython notebook server and a Mongod server processes running on that server. Whenever I logout, both of these processes die even though they are run in the background with `&`

I have recently discovered the `nohud` command which works fantastically. However, why is it that I have not encountered this with most servers? Is there some sort of default in unbuntu server that kills all processes by a user when they hangup from SSH? Can I run nohud by default for all processes?

Thank you

Comment: [Does getting disconnected from an SSH session kill your programs?](http://serverfault.com/q/463366/15051)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu processes handle signals the same way that other Linux distributions and Unices do.  When an SSH session disconnects, a SIGHUP signal is sent to the [session leader process](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html#ss10.3), which would probably be `bash`.

Bash, in turn, [cleans up after itself](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html#Signals):

> The shell exits by default upon receipt of a `SIGHUP`. Before exiting, an interactive shell resends the `SIGHUP` to all jobs, running or stopped. Stopped jobs are sent `SIGCONT` to ensure that they receive the `SIGHUP`. To prevent the shell from sending the `SIGHUP` signal to a particular job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the disown builtin (see [Job Control Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#Job-Control-Builtins)) or marked to not receive `SIGHUP` using `disown -h`.
>
> If the `huponexit` shell option has been set with `shopt` (see [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)), Bash sends a `SIGHUP` to all jobs when an interactive login shell exits.

`disown` is a Bash built-in command.  `nohup` is an external command with similar effect.

I don't recommend reconfiguring Bash to not kill all of its child processes (nor do I know how to do that).  Rather, a better goal would be to prevent Bash from dying when its TTY disappears.  You can use `screen`, `tmux`, or `mosh` to keep Bash alive.

Comment: Do you know if this is the same behavior with `csh` or `tcsh`?

Comment: It should be the same in `csh` or `tcsh`, except that [`nohup` is a builtin command](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html) in those shells, and `disown` is not.

Comment: Hmm, I can't figure it out. When I look at `shopt`, huponexit is set to off, but I can't figure out the other servers I have been apart of seem to never have this behavior. I could just login, run a job, then log off and that job would run until completion provided it was in the background. However, I was not the server admin, and do know if the SIGTERM was overloaded...but thank you for the info

Comment: If `huponexit` is enabled, Bash sends a `SIGHUP` to all jobs when an interactive login shell exits. However, when `huponexit` is disabled, it doesn't mean that Bash will not send a `SIGHUP` to any jobs; it means that the default behaviour takes place.

Comment: You may have been accustomed to running some processes that chose to "nohup" themselves automatically.

Comment: I have used `screen` in the past to keep a proces running in the background after closing the SSH-connection. It works like a charm. When you reconnect, you can list the open screens en regain control over them. Before you leave, you hide the screen again.